# Regex to match all occurances not surrounded by quote and stop at character

Tags: regex, regex-negation, regex-group

It's late here in europe and I can't get that regex running :-(
I want to match all text, that is **not** surrounded by quotes.

INPUT: Oh yeah this;input;'with quotes';can;'be very';tricky;'believe me';boy

It's really easy to match all text surrounded by quotes.

[DEMO](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%27%5b%5e%27%5d*%27%29&i=Oh+yeah+this%3binput%3b%27with+quotes%27%3bcan%3b%27be+very%27%3btricky%3b%27believe+me%27%3bboy)

But what I want is the opposite. Also the match should be splitted by ; so that I get the following matches:

1. Oh yeah this
2. input
3. can
4. tricky
5. boy

Any ideas before I get mad?

thx in advance!

Comment: Would be easier if you split the string first with the delimiter `;` into an array and then check if each of the array elements start and end with a `'`

Comment: or simply use the regex `(?<=^|;)[^';]+(?=;|$)` if look-arounds are supported [LINK](https://regex101.com/r/D9NAzo/2)

Comment: `((?<=(^|;))[^;]*[^'](?=($|;)))` is versatile enough

Comment: Your easy demo breaks if there is an apostrophe (or a forgotten quote). E.g. `Oh yeah this;input's value;'with quotes';can;'be very';tricky;'believe me';boy`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use a trick like this:

```
'[^;]*'(?=;|$)|([^;]+)(?=;|$)
```

Explanation:

```
'[^;]*'(?=;|$)      => finding words between `'` and ended with `;` or end of text, but not group it
|                   => or
([^;]+)(?=;|$)      => finding other words ended with `;` or end of text, but grouped
```

now you can use `$1` to catch what you want.

[**[ Regex Demo ]**](https://regex101.com/r/I4Z5w7/3)

Comment: Can be simplified to `(?:'[^;]+'|([^;]+))(?=;|$)`

Comment: No duplication of code. `(?=;|$)` is there twice, removing it in one spot simplifies the regex maintainability and uses 3 less characters. I do realize this solution causes a marginal amount of additional steps, but maintainability of code may be more important to the user. It should still be provided as an *option* to the user, so I don't see any harm in proposing a simplified pattern on top of your answer.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the regex

```
(?<=;|^)[^;'][^;]*[^;'](?=;|$)
```

see the [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/I4Z5w7/2), [regex storm demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C%3D%3B%7C%5E%29%5B%5E%3B%27%5D%5B%5E%3B%5D*%5B%5E%3B%27%5D%28%3F%3D%3B%7C%24%29&i=Oh%20yeah%20this%3Binput%3B%27with%20quotes%27%3Bcan%3B%27be%20very%27%3Btricky%3B%27believe%20me%27%3Bboy)